# Rails 6: why is it appending a number to the db name during model testing in a multi-db app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following multi-db setup in my rails 6.0.2.2 app:

```
development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: myapp_development
    migrations_paths: db/migrate/primary
  other:
    <<: *default
    database: other_development
    migrations_paths: db/migrate/other
```

When I try a run a model test for models in either db, I get

```
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' to database 'myapp_test-3'
```

For each test, it appends a different number to the db name.  The db user my_user does have access to the myapp_test db, but that obviously doesn't help when rails is adding a hyphen and an integer to the db name.

I've searched everything I can think of, but can't find any info.

Appreciate any info or suggestions (and apologies if I've missed something obvious)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check parallel testing in Rails 6. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#parallel-testing. That's why rails creates multiple DBs.

Comment: Ahh, I had mistakenly thought parallel testing was disabled by default, so I wasn't paying much attention to the details there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Take care.